# Signing Into Ubuntu One Account from Computer Settings

Tags: single-sign-on

I am new to the site and I have a question.  I created an Ubuntu One and Launchpad account.  I then went to my computer's settings and went to Online Accounts.  I tried to sign into my Ubuntu One account but all I get is an error.  I have checked and rechecked and my login credentials are correct.  Has anyone else had this problem?  I am running Ubuntu 18.4 and I have all of the latest updates.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in 18.04 LTS.

You must have `snapd` installed and running.

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

If it doesn't start by itself (this happend to me), run:

```
sudo service snapd start
```

Then try connecting to you Ubuntu One account again. Hope this helps.